# How to split 2 dimensional array and add array value to respective property of list

Tags: c#

```
string student = "[[999.33333333333,334.9949949994,-233333.44444,3499.4444444,-3939393.9393993993],
                [991.33333333333,331.9949949994,-233337.44444,34979.4444444,-8939393.9393993993]]";
```

need to split the <strike>array</strike>  string and need to display the following response structure

```
"headc":[
{
"head" : "999.33333333333" // first array value
"flow" : "991.33333333333,331" // second array value
},
{
"head" : "334.9949949994" // first array value
"flow" : "331.9949949994" // second array value
},
{
"head" : "-233333.44444" // first array value
"flow" : "-233337.44444" // second array value
},
{
"head" : "3499.4444444" // first array value
"flow" : "34979.4444444" //second array value
}
]
```

I have tried the following code

```
public class HeadCurve { 
    public string head { get; set; }
    public string flow { get; set; }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        List<HeadCurve> list = new List<HeadCurve>();
        HeadCurve headcurve = null;
        string student = "[[999.33333333333,334.9949949994,-233333.44444,3499.4444444,-3939393.9393993993]," +
                "[991.33333333333,331.9949949994,-233337.44444,34979.4444444,-8939393.9393993993]]";
        foreach (var i in student)
        {
            headcurve = new HeadCurve();
            foreach(var j in i.ToString())
            {
                if (headcurve == null) { headcurve.head = i.ToString(); }
                if (headcurve == null) { headcurve.head = j.ToString(); }
                Console.WriteLine("jjj" + j + ": ");
        }
        list.Add(headcurve);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: deserialize the input to a List<List<double>> and zip them then reserialize.

Comment: Perhaps first make an array of "someting" of the `string student =`

Comment: I edited your question to strike out the `array` to give clear focus on what you need to ask here.

Comment: A quick and easy solution is to `Split` by `],[` which will give you 2 `string` with each datasets. Then each string you want to remove all `[` and `]` and finally split each of them with `,` and you have both arrays correctly displayed. Then it's a matter of building your new format

Answer (score 1):

1/. Definning the input and expected output

First identify that your input is a Json, and drop it in any tool that generate class From a Json Like https://app.quicktype.io.
Identify that your result is a json , and copy past it in the same tool.

You now have :

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using System.Globalization;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string input = "[[999.33333333333,334.9949949994,-233333.44444,3499.4444444,-3939393.9393993993],"
                +"[991.33333333333,331.9949949994,-233337.44444,34979.4444444,-8939393.9393993993]]";
        
        var foo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<double>[]>(input); 


    }
}
public partial class Bar
{
    public List<Headc> Headc { get; set; }
}
public partial class Headc
{
    public string Head { get; set; }
    public string Flow { get; set; }
}
```

2/. Zip.

Read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?view=net-7.0 , and copy past the exemple in the solution.
Instead of numbers and words it's the First and Second element of the array.

```
var projection = 
     foo[0].Zip(foo[1], 
              (first, second) => 
              new Headc{
              Head = first.ToString()
              ,Flow=second.ToString()
            });
```

3/. Finalisation:

Wrap it in the class you got at step 1.

```
var result = new Bar{Headc=projection.ToList()};
```

[Live Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/SuDxl0)

Comment: What if the two arrays have different number of elements in them?

Comment: @PeterCsala The way the question is titled and the OP example is written this is not a possible input

Comment: @Franck Well, the requirements are so vague that we don't know whether it is a valid use case or not.

Comment: @PeterCsala, if input is not correct at least Op will have discovered quicktype.io and Zip.  Maybe The Real Treasure Was The Friends(and doc) We Made Along The Way.

Comment: var projection = 
     foo[0].Zip(foo[1], 
              (first, second) => 
              new Headc{
              Head = first.ToString()
              ,Flow=second.ToString()
            });

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution, in general I'd say people here all agree zip is you friend, here is just how I would do it, there are other ways that work just as well.

```
var arr = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<double[][]>(student);
var zippedValues = des2.Select((e,i) => e.Zip(des2[i], (f,s) => new { head = f, flow = s}));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want faster code that `JsonConvert`, parsing the string yourself is a good option and is at least 15 times faster (actually 18x on millions iteration test on the computer i am on right now). The code is not as simple but it is not too complex either. It can still be optimized (specially the double replace)

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string student = "[[999.33333333333,334.9949949994,-233333.44444,3499.4444444,-3939393.9393993993]," +
        "[991.33333333333,331.9949949994,-233337.44444,34979.4444444,-8939393.9393993993]]";
        
    var dataSets = student.Split(new[] { "],[" }, StringSplitOptions.None) // split the 2 set of X and Y values into 2 separate strings
                            .Select(o => // reformat the output
                                o.Replace("[", "").Replace("]", "")  // remove invalid characters in the string
                                .Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.None).ToList()) // split the values into array
                            .ToList(); // return as a list

    // zip (merge) the elements of both X and Y array at the same index into a new array
    var results = dataSets[0].Zip(dataSets[1],(first, second) => new [] { first, second }).ToList();  

    for (int i = 0;  i < results.Count; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("head : " + results[i][0] + " flow : " + results[i][1]);
    }
}
```